# Moment.js on meteor, Problems with Timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, momentjs

I've been trying to figure out the problem with moment-timezone.js. I can't seem to convert a timestamp from UTC to PST

The helper function I'm using is timeInTimeZone. Please excuse the horrible variable names.

Any help debugging the issue is much appreciated

```
Template.home.helpers({
  timezone: function() {
    return Template.instance().timezone.get();
  },
  timeInTimeZone : function(){
    let time   = moment( this.createdAt ),
        format = 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a';

    var timezone = Template.instance().timezone.get();
    console.log(time.format( format )); //works
    console.log(timezone); //works

    var editedTime = time.tz( timezone ).format( format ); //breaks
    console.log(editedTime);
    return editedTime;

  }
});
```

The log I get when using this is as follows:

> Saturday, February 17th 2018 1:11 am
>   home.js:141:5
>   America/Vancouver
>   home.js:142:5
>   Exception in template helper: timeInTimeZone@http://localhost:3000/app/client/views/pages/home.js?hash=f7d8b7711106080a4d6fbb1d2089cf344f59223d:143:22
>   bindDataContext/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3051:14
>   Blaze._wrapCatchingExceptions/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1715:14
>   wrapHelper/http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3103:14
>   Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3744:12
>   wrapHelper/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3102:12
>   Spacebars.call@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:172:12
>   Spacebars.mustacheImpl@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:106:10
>   Spacebars.mustache@http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?hash=547cf8e466d1d52603d19bd5f48fb5df184fd237:110:16
>   Template.homehttp://localhost:3000/app/client/views/pages/template.home.js?hash=be956f7036145947c4a904d9c42627576e740dd1:82:14
>   doRender@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2086:20
>   viewAutorun/http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1934:18
>   Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:3744:12
>   viewAutorun/<@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1932:14
>   Blaze._withCurrentView@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:2271:12
>   viewAutorun@http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?hash=a1ff2d6d5ecd59ee11e2ba260b8650a9d1140f59:1931:12
>   Tracker.Computation.prototype._compute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:339:5
>   Tracker.Computation.prototype._recompute@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:358:9
>   Tracker._runFlush@http://localhost:3000/packages/tracker.js?hash=0e8b5c18d543a28ce43b2f183c26b49ee62196af:532:9
>   onGlobalMessage@http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?hash=b0f12795c8cc1423b5850502871996903f947ed5:448:11

I tried re-installing moment and momnet-timezone using `meteor npm` and `meteor add`

I know it's something to do with the time.tz(), what's being passed to it is the following `America/Vancouver`

Comment: What's happening on line 143 of home.js? I presume where you have commented breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was digging through the documentation for moment, although I can't find a proper solution for the .tz() function

I ended up using this code

```
timeInTimeZone : function(){
    var date = moment.utc(this.createdAt); //take the date in UTC format
    return date.local().format("ddd, MMM D YYYY h:mma"); //Return the date in user's local time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the issue is here but you could try the alternative method of creating a timezoned moment. Using the function `moment.tz`, you can pass a date and a timezone.

```js
(function() {
  /* ignore */
  this.createdAt = moment();
  const Template = {
    instance: () => ({
      timezone: { get: () => 'America/Vancouver' }
    })
  }
  /* end */

  let timezone = Template.instance().timezone.get();
  let time = moment.tz(this.createdAt, timezone);
  let format = 'dddd, MMMM Do YYYY h:mm a';
  
  var editedTime = time.format(format);
  console.log(editedTime);
  return editedTime;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.14/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```